# Cert-Manager doesnt create https route

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

**Given:**
I want to run a web application with letsencrypt certs via cert manager

**Problem**
I can access the site with http but https doesnt work even I can see that cert-manager created a certificate which is also saved as a secret.

**What I did**

1.) I installed cert-manager with helm

```
helm install --name cert-manager --namespace kube-system stable/cert-manager rbac.create=false
```

then i applied my k8s yaml.

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: myEmail
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    http01: {}
---
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: myEmail
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    http01: {}
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-runtime
  labels:
    name: api-runtime
    app: api-runtime
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-runtime
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: clickouts-api-host
        image: microsoft/dotnet-samples:aspnetapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-host-svc
  labels:
    app: api-runtime
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: api-runtime
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: api
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.comt
    secretName: api-tls
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: api-host-svc
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: api-tls
spec:
  secretName: api-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: mydomain.com
  dnsNames:
  - mydomain.com
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingress: nginx-ingress
      domains:
      - mydomain.com
```

What am I missing to get also an https route?

Comment: I spot a typo in   tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.comt

Answer (score 1):

I spot a typo in tls: - hosts: - mydomain.comt